# Drawing zoom independent

Tags: openlayers-3

I need to draw vectors on the map and they must not scale when zooming (visible size should not vary). Placing them at lat/lng is easy but how can I avoid scaling with zoom, is there an example for Openlayers 3 ? Images would also suffice but I am not sure about performance as I need to rotate many.

Comment: ??? The idea with vectors on/in a map is that the scale when zooming. What are the purpose, with the vector layer? You could draw SVG vector on top of the map/openlayers, that are independent of OL.

Comment: I do not want them to be fully independent, only zoom independent. Can those SVG vectors be placed at given coords ?

Comment: @AndersFinn probably style icon ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not really need a vector so went for an icon + rotation.
I changed the title accordingly...
[ol.style.Icon](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html) does the job as I can set the rotation and it will not scale with the zoom.

Example: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/icon.html